# Cant create bookshelf orm Table in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

So, i dont seem able to create tables using the bookshelf orm in Node js and i cant quite figure out where is my mistake. Here is the code to create the table :

```
    function db_exportup(response){
    exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
            return knex.schema.createTable('users', function(table) {
            table.increments('id').primary();
            table.string('name');
        });
    };
    exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('users');
    };
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-type" : "text/plain"});
  response.write("Table created!");
  response.end();
}
```

Im calling it on the server.js when someone request "/services/adddb.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table was not created because the `knex.schema.createTable` method was not called. You only defined the `up` method in the `db_exportup` function but you did not call it.

To create the table on request to the `'/services/adddb.php'` route, you need to call the [knex.schema.createTable](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-createTable) method and return a response on successful execution of the promise object returned:

```
function db_exportup(request, response) {
  // Call the 'createTable' method
  knex.schema.createTable('users', function(table) {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.string('name');
  })
  .then(function() {
    // Table creation succeeded
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-type" : "text/plain"});
    response.write("Table created!");
    response.end();
  })
  .catch(function() {
    // Table creation did not succeed.
    response.write("Table was not created");
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @gnerkus !! I hadnt seen it before.
I'm now getting "Internal Server Error", hahah, do you have any ideas why this could be happening ?